# Can I change the fixed_count of a User in LoadShape?

Tags: locust

Can I change the fixed_count of a User in LoadShape ?

I have a LoadShapeClass that ramps up the user count until I hit a "load limit" (defined by several criteria like server load, response time and so forth).

I have a UserClass with fixed_count = 1. This class represents some specific activities that are not part of the regular User.

I would like to be able to scale that fixed_count with the number of users, adding an extra one when I hit a certain user count in the ramp.

I note that in the ramp class I can see the classes and fixed_count

```
        for v in self.runner.environment.user_classes:
            logger.info("we have class %s with %d", v, v.fixed_count)
            if v.__name__ == looking_for:
                v.fixed_count += 1
```

Should that be enough to change that value from within the tick()?
And will that work in distributed mode ?

I have a logger.info() in the on_start for the affected class and I am only seeing it the initial time (fixed_count = 1 to start), and not after that. That implies I am missing something here. Been rooting through the dispatch code with no enlightenment.

Also is there a way to set the rebalance flag from the LoadShapeClass ? The easy way would likely be to just use the config file with my shape class in it :-)
enable-rebalancing = True
I also tried adding on the command line too.

I did not see anything obvious in the code - just a reference to users_dispatcher._rebalance in test which does not look right to touch.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine LoadShapes with specific user classes, like this:  https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/custom-load-shape.html#restricting-which-user-types-to-spawn-in-each-tick

Comment: Thanks for the response Cyberwiz. I did try changing the user classes as in the example, but I have not managed to find a magical combo that works. I tried several things - including changing the fixed_count in the class, removing and re-adding the class from the user class list, adding in the class twice..... and each time self.runner.user_classes_count is reporting a count of 1 for the fixed class (which I had hoped would be 2) on subsequent ticks. I will be out of the office for the next couple of weeks - may try again when I get back.

Comment: stop using fixed_count :) why would you need that, now that you are manually setting the count for respective user types in the shape class? Telling locust you want a fixed count and then trying to override it in the shape class makes no sense (should probably raise a warning though)